# redirecting user to another page using header()

Tags: php, session, header

I've looked everywhere and tried all solutions but it's still not getting me anywhere. Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))

{


  header('Location: /public_html/index.php');
  exit;

}
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;

        header('Location: /public_html/index.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
    }
}

    ?>
```

When I upload this into my server and login it brings me to a blank php page. What am I doing wrong with this code? I've tried using " instead of ' . I'm trying to redirect the user to a page outside of the folder hence the "/public_html/". Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have no `session_start()`. Also,there is no `else` which covers not being logged in .

Answer (score 0):

if outside the folder than use

```
header("Location:../public_html/index.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting your URL with `/` and followed with the folder name means, you want to go to the top/root directory, and followed with the folder name you've specified.

For example: 
Getting to `/public_html` means you're redirecting to http://www.example.com/public_html which I believe to be non-existance in your case

To get around this problem, do this:
add a double dot: `..`

Getting to ../public_html means you're redirecting from  http://www.example.com/some_project/some_folder/ to http://www.example.com/some_project/public_html/ (for example).

refer to Vicky's answer,

```
header("Location:../public_html/index.php");
exit();
```

and do not forget to add the `exit();` in the end.

---

edit: Please cease using the ancient PHP-MySQL. There's a better alternative for you to use, for your own safety:

- [PHP MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [PHP PDO MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)